# Format large numbers with comma separation in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a formula in crystal report
if x = 1 and y <= 9 then {Table.Field}. Table.field will return a number. I want that number to be in the format ##,###,### i.e. comma separated in 000s.File>Options>Fields tab> Number> Number tab Customize has the following:
Thousands Separator is ticked and the symbol used is comma.
That does not return the number with comma separation. e.g. 1012760 should have been displayed as 1,012,760.
I then tried to replace with ToText({Table.Field},0,",") in the formula above. This keeps giving an error in the formula. Appreciate any one's help in the matter. Regards

Comment: What data type has your {Table.Field}? What is the error message in formula editor saying? The formula looks ok and should work with the input 1012760 (you can check that by replacing the field by the value within you formula). Note that changing the global options does not affect fields already inserted in the layout, but only those which are added afterwards.

Comment: Now I have run into another issue with that change. How do i prevent some of the fields from rounding e.g. i want 1012760 to read as 1,012,760 - which works with the above formula. However i dont want 2.330 to read as 2 or 5.5 to read as 6. I want them to return as is.

Comment: By the way I worked out the solution as below 
IF (Not IsNull({Table.Field}) ) THEN
    //Case 1: numbers with decimals
    IF (instr({Table.Field},".")) > 0 then 
        ToText(ToNumber({Table.Field}),LEN(MID({Table.Field},instr({Table.Field}, ".")+1))
    ,",")
    ELSE
    //Case 2: Numbers without decimals
        ToText(ToNumber({Table.Field}),0,",") 
ELSE
    {Table.Field}:

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
CStr({Table.Field}, “#,###,###”)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for your contribution. But could you please add an explanation even if it is only a brief one. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.